# Google maps does not work in woocommerce tabs

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

since this morning my site does not show google maps in the tab, but I did not make any change, I tryed to upload a backup but doesn't work.

Here the url of a page where google maps doesn't work

http://rome-holiday-accommodation.com/product/apartment-rental-near-colosseum/

Just for be clear, in other position maps works as the home page.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I've 2 api key for the same project, I deleted one and now it's working